# Who are the 7 sisters of Saraswati mentioned in Rig Veda?

Tags: rig-veda, saraswati

Rig Veda [VI.61.12](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_6/Hymn_61) says

> Seven-sistered, sprung from threefold source, the Five Tribes'
>   prosperer, she must be Invoked in every deed of might.

At another mantra in Rig Veda, seven rivers -  सप्त सिन्धून, were mentioned [(RV II.12.3)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02012.htm), as being freed by **Indra**.

My question is, does the word सप्त सिन्धून indicate, seven branches of Sindhu river or seven separate rivers?  And, is Sarswati included in सप्त सिन्धून - **seven rivers**?